# WP_Query no result if keyword contains number

Tags: wp-query, search

```
$args = [
        's' => $autocompleteTerm,
        'orderby' => 'modified',
        'fields' => 'all',
        'post_status' => array('publish','future'),
    ];

$posts_query = new \WP_Query($args);
return $posts_query->get_posts();
```

`$autocompleteTerm` is a string of what I am searching for, for example, if I publish an article with title 'top 10 candies'

when `$autocompleteTerm = 'top 10'`, return is empty.

it works if `$autocompleteTerm = 'top'` instead

Comment: You probably need to show how `$autocompleteTerm` is constructed to answer this.

Comment: updated my question

Comment: I have tested Your code and it is working fine by both values.

Comment: in that case seems related to my environment, i went ahead commented out all non official filter for 'posts_where' and still getting empty result for 'top 10'